# Best way to interact between 2 clients in an application

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to build an application that will have the following parameters:

1) 2 clients will be connect with each other, using the LAN or the Internet;

2) The first one will make something, like click in a button, for example, while the second one will be waiting;

3) After the first one end up, he finalize and pass to the second one the 'control' of the application.

My question:

- Which is the best way to build this 'client x client' app? It must have a server? (The first one -server- and the second one -client-). I don't know well this part (tcp, connections...) so I'm lost.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a server.
Just a [P2P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) communication using C# Sockets
Try to look for C# sockets tutorial. [Here a decent one](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server).

Comment: In internet connections you may required to have two static IP or a server for communications, but in LAN networks no server required

Comment: Thanks! I'll try both ways (lan/internet).